# VBA Pivot filter on multiple cell ranges applied to multiple tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

While this topic is widely discussed I've been unable to find a proper solution to this issue.

As a data analyst, I would like to apply filters across multiple pivot table based on values in multiple cell ranges.

I have looked for answers and tried to apply these solutions:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/950078-filtering-pivot-table-based-cell-value.html

and this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCJgCRuVU6c&t=201s

Specifically this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
    'A1 to A9 is touched
    If Intersect(Target, Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Sales Region")
NewCat = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A9").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With


End Sub
```

however, they do not apply 100% as firstly it doesn't update anything at all (no reponse) and secondly it only applies the filter to the first column even if it would work.

Please see attached photo of how I'd like the model to look.[image]

Above is of course not entirely true as the filtering options would remove many of the values in the tables.

The pivot tables have the IDs "PivotTable1" & "PivotTable2".
Worksheet is called "Sheet1".

I would like to be able to change these values and also the filter options (e.g. to include a Date value filter.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Also, if there are any other options that doesn't include VBA, these will also be well received.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you already tried to achieve this. Otherwise it is off-topic asking us to do all the work for you. See [ask].

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for the advice - I updated the question